# Intellij IDE, how to disable 'Unexpected Token' warning inspection result

Tags: intellij-idea, inspections

In Intellij IDE, how to disable `Unexpected Token` warning?

I killed every options in inspections menu. But it still tortures me...

[image]

CSS code:
[image: css code]

Comment: Post the code *here* and post the error *here*

Comment: Instead of disabling, why don't you [fix your bug](http://rajtoral.com/hack-for-a-specific-version-of-a-specific-browser-css/) by enclosing the user agent in quote marks?

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I consider fix that as you advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Unexpected token" highlighting reports incorrect syntax. It is not an inspection and cannot be disabled, because code where such an error is highlighted is definitely wrong and will not compile / work as expected.

The comment above tells you how to fix the syntax of your CSS so that it is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was minor. I had written the entire code outside of any method. It was just inside the class and hence this error was being shown as this code is unexpected in that area.